# html form reloads page on submit POST

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a very basic HTML `</form>`. But, when I try to submit it, it instantly reloads the page which is quite unexpected as it doesn't send a request to my express route. I searched for it and found the `.preventDefault()` function. But it doesn't seem to be working-

```html
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/send" onsubmit="submit()" >
<input type="text" />
<!-- Form Body-->
</form>
```

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form")
form.preventDefault(); //this is in the function submit()
```

Comment: it should be `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, I missed the Event Listener function:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form")
 form.addEventListener("submit",async e => {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```